# Обновление поля timestamp в классе SoftReference

Tags: java

В исходном коде класса `SoftReference` есть такое поле:

```
/**
 * Timestamp updated by each invocation of the get method.  The VM may use
 * this field when selecting soft references to be cleared, but it is not
 * required to do so.
 */
private long timestamp;
```

Согласно документации к методу, каждый вызов `get` должен приводить к обновлению поля `timestamp`. Но этого не происходит и я не могу понять почему. В качестве эксперемента написал такой класс:

```
import java.lang.ref.SoftReference;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class SoftReferenceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SoftReference<StringBuilder> softReference = new SoftReference<>(new StringBuilder());
        long timestamp = getTimestamp(softReference);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            checkTimestampChange(softReference, timestamp);
        }

    }

    private static void checkTimestampChange(SoftReference softReference, long timestampBefore) throws Exception {
        softReference.get();
        Thread.sleep(100);
        assert timestampBefore == getTimestamp(softReference);
    }


    private static long getTimestamp(Object object) throws Exception {
        Field timestampField = SoftReference.class.getDeclaredField("timestamp");
        timestampField.setAccessible(true);
        long timestamp = timestampField.getLong(object);
        timestampField.setAccessible(false);

        return timestamp;
    }
}
```

Код успешно выполнился без ошибок. **Не могу понять почему.**

Comment: В чем вопрос? Почему выполняется код или почему не обновляется поле?

Comment: @JVic ну если бы поле обновлялось, то и код бы не выполнился без ошибок))) Если вы видите разницу в вопросах, то пусть будет "почему не обновляется поле".

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/169883/ . Timestamp обновляется каждый раз при вызове метода get() (каждый раз, когда мы создаем strong-ссылку на объект), те как я понял она обновляется вот тут `new SoftReference<>(new StringBuilder());` А дальше уже магия GC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы смотрели исходный код `SoftReference`? Там есть поле `clock`, которое обновляется, если верить документации, во время вызова GC.

```
/**
 * Timestamp clock, updated by the garbage collector
 */
static private long clock;
```

И код метода `get`

```
public T get() {
    T o = super.get();
    if (o != null && this.timestamp != clock)
        this.timestamp = clock;
    return o;
}
```

У вас не меняется `timestamp`, потому что сборщик мусора не вызывается за время выполения цикла.

Если явно вызывать его, то `timestamp` обновляется:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    SoftReference<StringBuilder> softReference = new SoftReference<>(new StringBuilder());
    long timestamp = getTimestamp(softReference);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        checkTimestampChange(softReference, timestamp);
        System.gc();
    }

}

private static void checkTimestampChange(SoftReference softReference, long timestampBefore) throws Exception {
    softReference.get();
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println(timestampBefore == getTimestamp(softReference));
}
```

> true
>
> false
>
> false
>
> false
>
> ...

Если же убрать вызов `System.gc()` в приведенном выше коде, то видимо будет выводиться в вашем случае `true` (но гарантии никакой нет)

Comment: Да, действительно. Не заметил (